# Description attribute text not present in TagHelper ModelExpression Metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Trying to write a custom TagHelper to display the `Description` attribute of a model property. Everything seems to work otherwise, but the description text is not passed on to my ModelExpression Metadata, it remains `null`.

This is an asp.net core 2.1 app. I'm hitting a breakpoint in my TagHelper's `Process`, so it is being run. The `DisplayName` prop is correct in `For.Metadata`, so the `ModelExpression For` resolves correctly.

The Model is defined in another assembly than the code using it, can this be an issue?

Model:

```
public class MyModel {
  [Description("a description")]
  [DisplayName("display name")]
  public string MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

TagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("span", Attributes = AttributeName)]
    public class DescriptionTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string AttributeName = "asp-description-for";

        /// <summary>
        /// An expression to be evaluated against the current model.
        /// </summary>
        [HtmlAttributeName(AttributeName)]
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (output == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
            }

            if (!output.IsContentModified)
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "text-muted");
                output.Content.SetContent(For.Metadata.Description);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
<span asp-description-for="MyModel.MyProperty"></span>
```

Using intellisense, i can see that the `For.Metadata.Attributes` Collection contains a `DescriptionAttribute` with the correct text. Am i wrong to assume that the `Description` metadata should be this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, found out from [a github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/1251#issuecomment-173652121) that `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute` is not supported in asp.net core, and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute` has a `Description` attribute that populates the relevant metadata text in a `ModelExpression`

This was sort of hard to find documentation about, hopefully someone googling around finds help here.

tl;dr - change `[Description("blah")]` to `[Display(Description="blah")]`

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was absurdly hard to find.